# How can I install MySQL server on Debian Linux while offline?

Tags: linux, debian

I'm a Linux newbie. I want to install mysql-5.5.15-linux2.6-x86_64.tar.gz on a Debian box offline without using the `apt` command. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure you have all dependencies installed already? Otherwise it won't work. It's way safer to do it through apt...

Comment: What Debian version are you running (post output of `cat /etc/debian_version`)? Is your system really 64-bit (post output of `uname -a`)? Do you just want an offline-install of MySQL or is there a reason you want to use a `.tar.gz`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can install from source by

- Unzipping the source file
- Opening a terminal and going — via `cd` — to the directory where the source is
- Running the `make` command from the terminal, hoping a makefile was included with the source

This is the general way. If you perform a Google search, you'll get a more appropriate answer.

Comment: Also as @m0skit0 pointed out, dependencies have to be met.